# Detecting specific points in (noisy) dataset

Tags: machine-learning, python, signal-processing

In my recent work I've came across a problem where I need to find certain points in quickly oscillating data. Let's work with syntethic data instead of real measurements and ignore the noise for the time being. These points are called stationary phase points (SPP for short). For human eye they are quite easy to spot: the oscillation slows down locally. An example:

[image: See this picture]

Some important things to note:

- It's always a local maxima or minima (so a reliable peak detection algorithm can help a lot, which I've been  working on recently)
- The graph is ideally normalized to [-1, 1], in real measurements it's a little distorted
- Usually the [Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) is not satisfied at the borders of data and the oscillation is avaraged out. (In the synthetic data I created it's satisfied, see below for a real-world dataset.)
- The general number of SPPs are 1 or 2, 3 or 4 are really rare, but exist.
- A SPP can continiously move around in the x direction as conditions are changing, can vanish at the borders of x-axis, and also one SPP can separate into two different SPPs which are moving away from each other.

The main goal would be reliably monitoring these points movement (ideally in real time, but first the SPP detection from x-y data is the target).
There are some other generated graphs with indication for SPPs, and the last is from real data.

[image: 1st]
[image: 2nd]
[image: 3rd]
[image: 4th]

To solve this, my first thought is to detect all the extremal points in data, then generate their consecutive distances, and where that distance exceeds a certain threshold value, it's a SPP. But setting a good threshold, correctly identifying extremal points seems quite hard and unique for each graph.

**My question is:**
 Do you think it would worth using a machine learning tool there, and if yes, which algorithm would be the most suitable? As a physicist I'm inexperienced, I only have basic knowledge about ML (but willing to learn!) 
In general, can you think of any useful algorithm or idea for such situation?

Note: Mostly I'm working in Python with numpy/scipy.

As far as local max and min detection concerned I use `scipy.signal.find_peaks` and `scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt` along with `scipy.signal.savgol_filter`.

Comment: A very abstract path I see is to build models that best fit the whole data, then A) you could inspect the residuals and remove the parts of timeseries with highest residuals and refit the models, and B) just let them be, but in the forecast you can measure a residual of forecasted value from the forecast and if it is outside of prediction interval you detect an anomaly. However, by looking at the plots I can hardly say how to build the models based on such variation in peridicity. A recurrent neural network can be a candidate for the modelling technique.

Comment: Let's assume that y axis is intensity (I), x axis is angular frequency ($\omega$). The analitic formula is in the following form: $I(\omega) = c_1 + c_2 \cdot \cos(b_0 + b_1\cdot \omega + b_2 \cdot \omega^2 + b_3 \cdot \omega^3 + b_4 \cdot \omega^4 +b_5 \cdot \omega^5 + ... )$.
The problem with fitting is the amount of parameters needed. Without good inital guess the fit will fail most of the time. (By the way, that's a Taylor polynomial in the cos function. Usually we don't need higher than 5th order.)

Comment: OK, so this is synthetic, right? Can real data be even more complex or noisy? What about estimating spectrum in a moving window? Then look at dynamics of power of frequency, so that when the power peak goes to lower frequency (you established the threshold) it is the region with very low frequency compared to other parts of the series.

Comment: That's synthetic, the real data is noisy, mostly due to finite resolution of the used device and optical aberrations. That idea sounds interesting, I will try that.